# android local notifications from ANE

Tags: android, air

I am writing application on ActionScript for Android using Adobe AIR with native extentions. 
In my application I need to show every 2 hours some notifications.

I finded, that on Android I can do that with AlarmManager, which is accessible while device is not rebuted or switched off:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

And status notifications, which can notify only when my application is runnable:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

So the question is such: How can I run application with AlarmManager, in my application handle case that I runned my application from AlarmManager (not manually by user) to start run from that method status notification to NotitificationManager?? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to trigger an Alarm with AlarmManager, catch that with a BroadcastReciever and Trigger from there your Notification. It seems very overhelming not be able to "Post a Notification at Time" but is currently the only way I know

Comment: Thanks, but I need to do it from ANE